# Setting the root node of tree to None

Tags: python-3.x

When deleting the root (that happens to be a leaf itself) in a one node tree, I need to change the root node to be just None. I dont want to get an empty node of self.value = self.left = self.right = None.

I tried setting self = None as shown in the code below, but it doesnt work for some reason, nor deleting (del self) works either. Its easy to delete leaves because you only need to set the previous.right = None or previous.left = None and thats it. But there is no reference to the root obviously to help with this case.

Is it even possible to change the type of the root from a binary node and make it None or even an integer or such? Because as you see in the code, setting self doesnt work

```
class BinaryNode:
    def __init__(self, value, left = None, right = None):
        '''
        Initiate a Binary-tree
        :param value: float | int | str
        :return: None
        '''
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def delete_root(self):
        '''
        Delete the root of the tree
        :return: None
        '''
        if not(self.right or self.left): #Base case: the root is childless
            self = None              #Doesnt work!!! 
        else:
            self.left.get_max() #get_max is a method that replaces the root with a leaf
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no way you can do that. The references to the root node are held somewhere else (such as local variables in various user functions), and the class itself can't change those references.

What you may want to do instead is add an extra layer of indirection, between the user code and the root node. Often this is a `Tree` class of some sort, and in addition to the (possibly `None`) root node reference, it can also keep track of other useful things, like how many values are in the tree.